# matplotlib double axis with one being text

Tags: matplotlib

I want to create a plot like this:

[image]

in which the upper x-axis is just a text like this code:

```
x=[4,5,13]
xa=['11','7','14']// which could have been ['apple','orange','lemon']
y=[4,11,9]
ax1.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

I also want to have the x-axis below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[4,5,13]
xa= ['apple','orange','lemon']
y=[4,11,9]
ax1 = plt.axes()
ax1.plot(x,y)
ax1.xaxis.tick_top()
ax1.xaxis.set_ticks(x)
ax1.xaxis.set_ticklabels(xa)
ax1.secondary_xaxis('bottom')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you but I want my first axis also, I have modified my code and added an x list so I wanna plot them both, in which the data places in x direction correspond to x.

Comment: I tried ```import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xa= ['apple','orange','lemon']
y=[4,11,9]
ax1 = plt.axes()
ax1.plot(x,y)
ax2=ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(xa,y)
ax2.xaxis.tick_top()
ax2.secondary_xaxis('bottom')
plt.show()``` but didnt work.

Comment: @FarhangAmaji, see the updated answer above.

Comment: I cant give you double thumbs up for each axis. <3